# Added repository unused

Tags: apt, add-apt-repository, ardour

I wanted to install Ardour 6 today. As suggested [here](https://ubuntustudio.org/2020/06/ardour-6-0-information/), I did

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntustudio-ppa/ardour-backports
```

then

```
apt search ardour
```

but it still shows me the 5.12 version. What's wrong? How can I debug this issue? I already checked the `/etc/apt` folder and it looks okay.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? The PPA only hosts packages for 20.04

Comment: I am still using the latest LTS version, 20.04, which I originally upgraded from 18.04.

Comment: Run `sudo apt update` and try again.

Comment: Thanks, it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely, it did install Ardour 6 now. I moved the kxstudio sources away from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, did an `apt update`, then install ardour.

I have done this previously already to no success. But at that time, Ardour 5.12 was already installed and it reported that no newer version is available. Later, I `apt remove ardour`.

I assume that it did worked now because ardour wasn't installed, but I haven't verified this.